# Can I have Admin edit the shipping costs after an order is placed by user?

Tags: magento

I'm wondering if it's possible to enable the Magento admin to edit the cost of shipping for an order already placed?

Comment: It's not a feature of the admin, but you can go in to the database and change the shipping and totals amount in the sales_flat_* tables. Just be careful and consistent. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Magento is pretty limited when it comes to modifying existing orders.

You can extend the core functionality by using a 3rd Party Extension, such as [Re - Authorize + Order Editor + Grid manager + Invoice Editor](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/order-editor-6982.html)

That extension will include the functionality to modify the shipping method and prices on existing orders.